# Sort subarray inside a grouped dictionary

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary

I have 3 arrays which I have to merge for same year. I have done that and then I made groups using `Dictionary.init(grouping: weatherDataArray)` and now I am trying to sort a grouped dictionary. Here is an example of data I have :

```
[2008: [["year": 2008, "month": 12, "rainfallValue": 87.9000015, "tminValue": 0.200000003, "tmaxValue": 6.0999999], ["year": 2008, "month": 11, "rainfallValue": 106.400002, "tminValue": 0.200000003, "tmaxValue": 6.0999999], ["year": 2008, "month": 10, "rainfallValue": 155.699997, "tminValue": 0.200000003, "tmaxValue": 6.0999999], ["year": 2008, "month": 9, "rainfallValue": 106.300003, "tminValue": 0.200000003, "tmaxValue": 6.0999999], ["year": 2008, "month": 8, "rainfallValue": 133.600006, "tminValue": 0.200000003, "tmaxValue": 6.0999999], ["year": 2008, "month": 7, "rainfallValue": 108.099998, "tminValue": 0.200000003, "tmaxValue": 6.0999999], ["year": 2008, "month": 6, "rainfallValue": 78.5, "tminValue": 0.200000003, "tmaxValue": 6.0999999], ["year": 2008, "month": 5, "rainfallValue": 47.9000015, "tminValue": 0.200000003, "tmaxValue": 6.0999999], ["year": 2008, "month": 4, "rainfallValue": 76.1999969, "tminValue": 0.200000003, "tmaxValue": 6.0999999], ["year": 2008, "month": 3, "rainfallValue": 122.5, "tminValue": 0.200000003, "tmaxValue": 6.0999999], ["year": 2008, "month": 2, "rainfallValue": 82.3000031, "tminValue": 0.200000003, "tmaxValue": 6.0999999], ["year": 2008, "month": 1, "rainfallValue": 189.600006, "tminValue": 0.200000003, "tmaxValue": 6.0999999]], 1992: [["year": 1992, "month": 6, "rainfallValue": 38.5999985, "tminValue": 3.20000005, "tmaxValue": 5.80000019], ["year": 1992, "month": 5, "rainfallValue": 57.2999992, "tminValue": 3.20000005, "tmaxValue": 5.80000019], ["year": 1992, "month": 4, "rainfallValue": 88.0, "tminValue": 3.20000005, "tmaxValue": 5.80000019], ["year": 1992, "month": 3, "rainfallValue": 125.0, "tminValue": 3.20000005, "tmaxValue": 5.80000019], ["year": 1992, "month": 2, "rainfallValue": 87.5, "tminValue": 3.20000005, "tmaxValue": 5.80000019], ["year": 1992, "month": 1, "rainfallValue": 77.4000015, "tminValue": 3.20000005, "tmaxValue": 5.80000019], ["year": 1992, "month": 12, "rainfallValue": 105.0, "tminValue": 3.20000005, "tmaxValue": 5.80000019], ["year": 1992, "month": 11, "rainfallValue": 158.5, "tminValue": 3.20000005, "tmaxValue": 5.80000019], ["year": 1992, "month": 10, "rainfallValue": 94.5, "tminValue": 3.20000005, "tmaxValue": 5.80000019], ["year": 1992, "month": 9, "rainfallValue": 115.5, "tminValue": 3.20000005, "tmaxValue": 5.80000019], ["year": 1992, "month": 8, "rainfallValue": 157.300003, "tminValue": 3.20000005, "tmaxValue": 5.80000019], ["year": 1992, "month": 7, "rainfallValue": 84.1999969, "tminValue": 3.20000005, "tmaxValue": 5.80000019]]]
```

**Basically `[Int: [[String: Any]]]` type.**

So I get groups as years, my goal is to make an array which is sorted by year as well as months in `ascending` order basically `[[String: Any]]` which will show 1992 data first and months will go from 1-12 and then 2008 and months related to this year from 1-12.

What should be the next step ? Or is there a diff approach to do it ?

Comment: Please post a correct json (not just portion of it), so that everyone can use beautifier.

Comment: @RatulSharker Data is huge, I have updated the data structure for reference.

Comment: then post a few which can be beatuified using any online json beautifier like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

Comment: @RatulSharker Updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first sort the grouped dictionary based on the keys, such that you get an array of tuples, which is sorted by the year, then call `map` on that and return the value, which is the array of dictionaries and sort them inside the `map` call based on the month.

I stored the values in your question in `groupedDict`.

```
let sortedArrFromDict = groupedDict.sorted(by: {$0.key < $1.key}).flatMap({$0.value.sorted(by: {$0["month"]! < $1["month"]!})})
print(sortedArrFromDict)
```

Comment: Awesome!!. Just one thing, I am getting `[ [ [String: Any] ] ]` but I need `[ [ String: Any] ]`. Any help on this ?

Comment: @SharadChauhan check my updated answer, you just need to change `map` to `flatMap`